# How to display Bestseller and Most Viewed Section product display in admin grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.5

Hello I am using magento2.3.5 in my admin panel Best seller product and Most viewed product not showing the product list , it shows "We couldn't find any records.", please help me there is any setting to do turn on or off. i am attach the image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your Magento admin panel go to the

> Reports -> Statistics -> Refresh Statistics -> Select all -> Select

option called "`Refresh Statistics for the last day`" and click on submit

Same way select option called "**Refresh Lifetime Statistics**" -> and click on submit button

Now clear the cache and check your dashboard it will showcase values under each tab

Comment: Yes i done already and best seller result got but Most viewed Results are not comed

Comment: @Magento Go to `Admin => Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Recently Viewed/Compared Products select Yes` to ( Synchronize widget products with backend storage )
Clear cache and check.